# Como cambio el formato extraño que me aparece al usar Matlab R2013a

Tags: matlab, formato

El comando que que he digitado en el Matlab R2013a que tengo es el siguiente.

```
syms t s
 b=1/(s^2+3*s+4);
>> ilaplace(b*laplace(t+4))
ans =
  13
  -- + 1/4 t
  16

                                   1/2          1/2                  1/2
         - 1/112 exp(- 3/2 t) (47 7    sin(1/2 7    t) + 91 cos(1/2 7    t))
```

El formato con el que aparece no es comodo ni correcto, ¿como hago que mi respuesta aparezca mas legible?

Comment: Estoy tentado de editar tu pregunta y responder "de nada". Podrías quizás agregar en texto o etiqueta en que contexta te aparece este formato?

Comment: @StefanNolde ya edité la pregunta, especificando que es al digitar el codigo en Matlab R 2013a

Comment: Hay una etiqueta para matlab, las etiquetas ayudan a los usuarios de encontrar publicaciones de sus temas preferidos. Te lo añadí.